# How do I use 'notify-send' to immediately replace an existing notification?

Tags: command-line, bash, notification, notify-osd

When I use `notify-send` to show a notification on the desktop, and then use it again to show a different notification, I have noticed that the second one only shows *after* the first one has disappeared.

Is there a way to get `notify-send` to immediately replace an existing notification with a different one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### You can, but you must use a patched *libnotify* to do so (update: no longer needed since 22.10)

`notify-send` does not have the capability to replace existing notifications before they have timed out (or disappeared). This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/257135). However, a commenter on the bug report [has posted a patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/257135/comments/10) to fix it.

**Update:** the patch was merged in libnotify 0.7.10, which was released on 27 April 2022 and first included in Ubuntu 22.10.

#### Installing the patched *libnotify-bin* from PPA

I have created a patched version of the *libnotify-bin* package which allows replacements in my PPA. Currently it's for Ubuntu 12.04 only, but if you need it for any other currently supported release, please post a comment and I will try my best to make it available.

To install, open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:izx/askubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

#### How to use the replacement capabilities

The patched `notify-send` includes two new switches, `-p` (or `--print-id`), and `-r` (or `--replace-id`). The `--help` describes them as:

```
-p, --print-id                    Print the notification ID.
-r, --replace-id=REPLACE_ID       The ID of the notification to replace.
```

- With `-p`, each `notify-send` will output an ID *N* (number/integer).
- Issuing another `notify-send` with `-r N` will replace the previous notification *immediately*.
- For example, for bash, you can save the ID from `notify-send -p ...` with:

  ```
  NID=$(notify-send -p "MESSAGE-1")
  ```

  and then replace it with:

  ```
  notify-send -r $NID "MESSAGE-2"
  ```
- You can repeatedly use both `-p` and `-r` in a script, as long as the `-r` ID is initialized to 0 at the beginning.
- Here's a simple script that shows notifications counting from 0 to 100 at half-second intervals:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  NID=0
  for i in {0..100..10}; do
      NID=$(notify-send -p -r $NID $i)
      sleep 0.5
  done
  ```

Comment: I get 404 for http://ppa.launchpad.net/izx/askubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages. Is this repository outdated?

Comment: You can use my python script that works like notify-send: https://github.com/phuhl/notify-send.py

Comment: On 22.04 I installed [libnotify4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libnotify4/download) and [libnotify-bin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libnotify-bin/download) from 22.10 and it's working without issue (so far).

Answer (score 16):

You can use the "synchronous" hint to create a "confirmation" notification that will replace previous confirmation notifications.  For example:

```
notify-send "Message" -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything
```

The "x-canonical-private-synchronous" hint is specified in [this document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD).  To specify a hint, use `-h type:name:value`.  The type here is `string`, name is `x-canonical-private-synchronous`, and it seems that the value can be whatever you want.

So if your first notification is created with that hint *and* the second is as well, the second will immediately replace the first.  (See [Animations and Durations](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#Animations_and_durations) in the documentation, in the column for "confirmation bubbles".)

Comment: `string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything` was exactly what i needed. Thanks for this answer. Also for linking to the documentation

Comment: It doesn't work with GNOME....

Comment: This somewhat obviously only works on ubuntu.

Comment: ...and it does not work on the Ubuntu-derived Pop!_OS 22.04

Answer (score 10):

X-ref:
[How to force a new Notification in notify-osd to show up without waiting for the earlier one to exit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161662/how-to-force-a-new-notification-in-notify-osd-to-show-up-without-waiting-for-the?rq=1)

without patches you can simply do

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..100..10}
    do
          killall notify-osd
          notify-send "testing" $i
          sleep 1
    done
```

Bookmark:
[How do I use 'notify-send' to immediately replace an existing notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161851/how-do-i-use-notify-send-to-immediately-replace-an-existing-notification/190397#190397)

---

Sends an error notify-osd(2592): Operation not permitted. What does that mean?

It may mean that privileges are inadequate requiring:

```
sudo killall notify-osd
```

Comment: Sends an error `notify-osd(2592): Operation not permitted`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple python script that works nearly the same as notify-send but has support for `--replaces-id`.

## notify-send.py

**web:** https://github.com/phuhl/notify-send.py

A python script for sending desktop notifications from the shell.

#### About

Libnotify is part of many scripts in the Linux world. It utilizes many
of the specified features of the Desktop Notifications Specification
and makes them accessible to shell-scripts. It does *not* however
allow to replace an existing notification with the `replaces-id`. This
is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/257135) since 2008 and has a [patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/257135/comments/10) since 2012. The patch is still not
upstream though (2018).

This python script utilizes the **notify2** package and exposes the
functionality to the shell.

#### Differences between notify-send.py and notify-send

- In `notify-send.py -h`  shows help instead of being the parameter for
  hints. For hints use `--hint`.
- In `notify-send.py -r ID` and `notify-send.py --replaces-id ID`
  exists. In order to replace a notification call `notify-send.py`
  with the ID that was returned by the notification to be replaced.
- `notify-send.py` returns the ID of the newly created notification.
- `notify-send.py --replaces-process NAME` exists.
  Every notification that gets created with the same NAME will replace
  every notification before it with the same NAME. If called with this
  parameter `notify-send.py` might block, best to be called with a
  trailing `&`.

#### Installation

Requires python3.

```
git clone https://github.com/phuhl/notify-send.py
cd notify-send.py
sudo pip install notify2
sudo python setup.py install
```

#### Usage

```
$ notify-send.py -h
usage: notify-send.py [-h] [-u LEVEL] [-t TIME] [-a APP_NAME]
                  [-i ICON[,ICON...]] [-c TYPE[,TYPE...]]
                  [--hint TYPE:NAME:VALUE] [-r ID]
                  [--replaces-process NAME]
                  SUMMERY [BODY]

positional arguments:
      SUMMERY
      BODY

optional arguments:
      -h, --help        show this help message and exit
      -u LEVEL, --urgency LEVEL
                        Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).
      -t TIME, --expire-time TIME
                        Specifies the timeout in milliseconds at which to
                        expire the notification.
      -a APP_NAME, --app-name APP_NAME
                        Specifies the app name for the icon
      -i ICON[,ICON...], --icon ICON[,ICON...]
                        Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.
      -c TYPE[,TYPE...], --category TYPE[,TYPE...]
                        Specifies the notification category.
      --hint TYPE:NAME:VALUE
                        Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid typesare
                        int, double, string and byte.
      -r ID, --replaces-id ID
                        Specifies the id of the notification that should be
                        replaced.
     --replaces-process NAME
                        Specifies the name of a process that should take care
                        of replacing notifications for this process.
```

#### notify-send[.py] as root user

In order to display notifications, even if libnotify or

```
notify-send.py
```

is used from the root user these two scripts are helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
username=<your username here>
if [ "$(id -u)" != "1000" ] ; then
    sudo -u $username DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send.sh "$@"
else
    notify-send.sh "$@"
fi
```

With  `notify-send.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send.py "$@" &
```

#### See also

Also take a look at my [notification-daemon](https://github.com/phuhl/linux_notification_center) inspired by [Dunst](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dunst), but with several improvements, including the possibility of a transparent background and a notification center that stores notifications.

Comment: This solution worked for me on ubuntu 18.10. None of the other solutions seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of [Mark L's Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/871207/307523):

[image: tvpowered volume.gif]

With this method a **confirmation** bubble is sent overlapping the top panel bar. Traditionally a **notification** bubble which appears lower below the top panel bar.

A notification bubble usually lasts a few seconds but in above `gif` the confirmation bubble is immediately replaced by the next one. The method is to call the `notify-send` command in a loop:

```bsh
# Make volume bar using progress bar methods
VolumeBar $CurrVolume
# Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/871207/307523
notify-send --urgency=critical "tvpowered" \
    -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:volume \
    --icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/devices/audio-speakers.png \
    "Volume: $CurrVolume $Bar"
```

In above code snippet the function `VolumeBar` sets the variable `$Bar` with a progress bar based on the value passed in `$CurrVolume`.

Answer (score 0):

Using gdbus call (working on Debian 10)

```
#!/bin/bash

last_id='0'

for i in {0..10}; do

    volume=$(( i * 10 ))

    r=$(gdbus call \
        --session \
        --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications \
        --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
        --method org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
        'Xfce volume control' \
        "$last_id" \
        'audio-volume-medium-symbolic' \
        "Volume $volume%" \
        '' \
        '[]' \
        "{'x-canonical-private-synchronous': <''>, 'transient': <true>, 'value': <$volume>}" \
        2000)

    last_id="${r:8:-2}"

    sleep 0.5

done
```

With the help of `dbus-monitor`, [this blog post](https://sylvaindurand.org/update-notifications-with-libnotify/) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698201/make-a-new-notification-with-sound-icon-and-bar)