# Indicator, notifier and blocker of Internet traffic

Tags: networking, internet, indicator, notification, traffic

Which traffic monitor applications currently available can do the following things? (or some of them, in the worst case)

- start **recording** how much Internet data is downloaded and uploaded with a connection managed by Ubuntu's default Network Manager
- **show** the current amount of traffic reached since that date and time by an indicator **in the notification area** (right part of the Unity top panel) and by an equivalent element in KDE
- **notify** with a **pop-up message** or similar method each time a user-defined amount of traffic has been reached (for example every 500 MegaBytes)
- set in a "**pause**" condition the Internet activity if a user-defined amount of traffic has been reached (i.e. the connection is kept on)

**I'm using [NTM](http://netramon.sourceforge.net/eng/index.html) but it's limited**: it records and shows the current amount of traffic in a floating window, not in the notification area; it notifies basing on time periods, not on data amounts; it can't pause the Internet activity.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with 1st two choices.I mean starting monitor with current usage and showing total usage in month wise.

the application named as vnstat.you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

then type as

```
vnstat
```

it will show you the usage statistics.

Comment: vnstat only satisfies 1.5 out of 4 requirements, doesn't it?

Comment: @Its 2. not 1.5 . I am using it.

Comment: "show the current amount of traffic reached since that date" - yes; "and time by an indicator in the notification area (right part of the Unity top panel) and by an equivalent element in KDE" - no. Therefore 1.5. Regardless, wouldn't it be better to post an incomplete answer as a comment?

Comment: @Pavel nothing is better than something. If he know some bash script then he can use notifysend to get notifications and then set some alert scipt with vnstat.

Comment: Thank you, I'd like these kind of hints too, if such an application doesn't exist yet. If I have sufficient indications and the commands are not difficult I could reach what I need without a single application.

Comment: @Andrew thank you . if you want to know about notify send pop up http://askubuntu.com/questions/161851/how-do-i-use-notify-send-to-immediately-replace-an-existing-notification