# How do I create a fake process bar?

Tags: command-line

I want the terminal to show some kind of process bar based on time, like 1% every 60 seconds for example.

Comment: See [How to add a progress bar to a shell script? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238073/4518341)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a progress bar in bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747143/create-a-progress-bar-in-bash)

Comment: **To reviewers**: IMO this is neither unclear nor a duplicate to the linked question, it asks precisely for a *fake* progress bar and is quite clear about the fake data. If you consider this unclear nevertheless, please add a comment explaining how OP can improve the question.

Comment: @dessert Re my dupe flag, I don't see how a fake progress bar is different from a real one. **Edit**: after reading your answer, I think I get it, but I could still use some clarity.

Comment: @wjandrea I took it the question is how to create fake data that's useful in conjunction with the different progress bar solutions, so I tried to cover everything (besides custom scripts, added an own section for that) mentioned in the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747143/create-a-progress-bar-in-bash). That's just how I read the question though, please feel free to ask OP to clarify!

Comment: Most of the progress bar examples I've seen online are fake in the first place so people can copy and paste them :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Create a progress bar in bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747143/create-a-progress-bar-in-bash) lists approaches to get a progress bar, so I'll concentrate on the *How to fake* part here. I'll use 2 seconds instead of your 60 here just for testing, adjust the `sleep` value to your exact needs.

#### Using `dialog`, `whiptail` or `zenity` (GUI)

```bsh
for i in {1..100}; do sleep 2; echo $i; done | dialog --gauge 'Running...' 6 60 0
```

This `for` loop loops<sup>1</sup> over the numbers one to hundred and `echo`s them every `2` seconds, the output is then piped to `dialog`, which shows the number as the progress on a progress bar. This approach works for `whiptail` and `zenity --progress` (GUI) as well. `dialog`'s output looks like this with a colored progress bar using 'curses' in text mode:

[image: dialog progress bar]

#### Using `pv`

```bsh
for i in {1..100}; do sleep 2; echo; done | pv -pWs100 >/dev/null
```

This  loop is very similar, just that it prints only a newline (=1 byte of data) every `2` seconds, `pv` is then told to expect exactly `100` bytes of data and show a `p`rogress bar. In a terminal window with a width of 80 characters the output looks like this:

```bsh
[===============>                                                          ] 22%
```

#### Constructing your own progress bar

With a simple loop you can also construct your own progress bar. Here are some examples that just print 100 `#` in one line, one per 2 seconds:

```bsh
# number signs only
$ for i in {1..100}; do sleep 2; echo -n \#; done; echo
####################################################################################################

# with progress in % on the right
$ for i in {1..100}; do sleep 2; printf "%0.s#" $(seq 1 $i); printf "%0.s " $(seq $i 100); printf "%3d%%\r" "$i"; done; echo
######################################################                                                54%

# with progress in % on the left
$ for i in {1..100}; do sleep 2; printf "%3d%% " "$i"; printf "%0.s#" $(seq 1 $i); printf "%0.s " $(seq $i 100); printf "\r"; done; echo
 39% #######################################
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> Look, a [Polyptoton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyptoton)!</sup>

Answer (score 3):

### Fake Progress Bar

This progress bar uses real data in `/bin` directory which everyone has. The script can be "dumbed down" to suit your fake needs. Or it can be expanded for a real life application:

[image: yad-progress-bar.gif]

It uses `yad` which is a super-charged version of `zenity` the default GUI used in the terminal. To install `yad` use:

```
sudo apt install yad
```

Here's the code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: yad-progress-bar
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Display yad progress bar % with names.
# DATE: Apr 23, 2018.  Modified Oct 18, 2019.

Source="/bin"
Title="Processing files for: $Source"
Count=0  
AllFiles=$(ls $Source/* | wc -l)

for f in "$Source"/* ; do

    echo "#$f"              # Display file name in progress bar.
    Count=$(( $Count + 1 ))
    Percent=$(( Count * 100 / AllFiles ))
    echo $Percent           # Display percent complete in progress bar.
    sleep .025

done | yad --progress       --auto-close \
    --width=500             --height=300 \
    --title="$Title"        --enable-log "Current filename" \
    --log-expanded          --log-height=250 \
    --log-on-top            --percentage=0 \
    --no-cancel             --center
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over /usr/bin? Why not just use `for i in {1..100}` or `i=100; while ((--i))` ?

Comment: Two notes: 1) Use the newer command substitution syntax `$()` instead of backticks, which are deprecated. 2) It would be cleaner to put the `yad` options in an array.

Comment: @wjandrea I looped through `/usr/bin` to give some text to the progress display. I know backticks are frowned upon these days but it was old code I had laying around which I copied without doing a lot of work. I've removed them. The `yad` options in an array does clean up the `done` line but I think this method illustrates to newcomers what is going on with the pipe to `yad` with all the details in one spot.

Comment: +1 for… a nice answer. ;D OP asked for ***the terminal** to show some kind of process bar*, which is why I concentrated on non-GUI solutions, but this is not at all detrimental to the usefulness of your approach. Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comment from @wjandream and just using for i in {1..100}, the third option is reduced to:

> for ((i=0; i<=100; i++)); { echo "$i"; echo "# Downloading $i%";sleep 0.2; } | yad --progress --title="Downloading..." --height=90 --width=400 --center --text="Please wait..." --auto-close --no-buttons --no-escape