# How to display progress when formatting a partition?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, disk-formatting

I am creating an ext4 partition in my external USB stick from CLI. While I am able to do this successfully with `mkfs`, I haven't found a way to display a progress bar (or percentage) while formatting.

Is there another command/package (or flag) that provides that kind of information?

Comment: with python it should be possible! Hah I see bash is capable look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script

Comment: thank you for the information.. i have already seen that post but i cannot use python. I am on a very resource limited embedded environment

Comment: There is a cool script there pmonitor did you try that

Comment: i just tried to use it but it didnt work (or at least it didnt with the command i used)

Comment: maybe using directly the PID will work but it is not very useful when the formatting time is short (small partition/usb)

Comment: You need to hold off on that pmonitor tool as it has awk issues and there is a current open pull request for a fix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a progress bar in Bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747143/create-a-progress-bar-in-bash)