# Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?

Tags: notification, dbus

ref:
[Close button on notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14354/close-button-on-notify-osd/189956#189956)

Bookmark:
[Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in)

Currently, this script

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" |             \
grep --line-buffered "member=Notify"                     |             \
sed -u -e  's/.*/killall notify-osd/g'                   |             \
bash
```

will kill all pending notifications.

It would be better to finesse the specific target OSD notification to cancel, by using  `org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id)`. Is there an interface method that can put this on (in?) the DBus to fire when a particular notify event occurs?

The method will need to get the notify PID to use as the argument for `CloseNotification(uint id)`. Alternatively,

```
  qdbus    org.freedesktop.Notifications                \
          /org/freedesktop/Notifications                \
           org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id)
```

could be used from the shell, if the `(uint id)` argument could be determined. The actual command syntax would use an integer in place of `(uint id)`.

Perhaps a better question to ask first might be "How is a notification's DBus address found?".
Neither of these identify it correctly:

```
gdbus monitor --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

returns

```
The name org.freedesktop.Notifications is owned by :1.130
...
```

or

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
```

returns

```
... string ":1.340" ...
```

In hindsight, the previous question "How is the `(uint id)` for a notification found?"is rhe torical given this previous answer to another question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/186311/89468
provides details so either method below can be used:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.DBus                                   \
             --object-path /                                                       \
                   --method org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID :1.16
```

returning:

```
(uint32 8957,)
```

or

```
qdbus --literal --session  org.freedesktop.DBus                                  \
                          /                                                      \
                           org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID :1.16
```

returning:

```
8957
```

The pop-up notify-OSD graffit would be then defeated with:

```
  qdbus    org.freedesktop.Notifications                             \
          /org/freedesktop/Notifications                             \
           org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification           \
  $(qdbus --literal --session                                        \
           org.freedesktop.DBus                                      \
          /                                                          \
           org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID :?.???  )
```

The "trick" is to find the `:?.???` DBus address.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know what `(UINT32 id)` is or is not?

Given the statement `You ... need a way to get that ID ...` in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/190672) and the following empirical observations perhaps the title of the question should be changed to "How can `gdbus ... -m org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification ...` close a notification?"

Is it by implication or process of elimination that the statement "... it only states that the ID is to be unique, non-zero, and less than MAXINT ...", found in the description of [9.1.2. org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html#command-notify), also applies to the `CloseNotification` parameter `(UINT32 id)`? The `UINT32` by process of elimination is the only common factor as an attribute type in the documentation and there is the  implication that there must be some sort of common ID "handle" but ...

The details of the returned value of `Notify` and its parameter `UINT32 replaces_id` are quite explicit but it is not clear that `CloseNotification`'s `(UINT32 id)` has anything to do with that as demonstrated with empirical testing below.

Quoting [9.1.3. org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html#command-close-notification) in toto:

```
9.1.3. org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification

void org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification (UINT32 id);

Causes a notification to be forcefully closed and removed from the user's view.
It can be used, for example, in the event that what the notification pertains to
is no longer relevant, or to cancel a notification with no expiration time.

The NotificationClosed signal is emitted by this method.

If the notification no longer exists, an empty D-BUS Error message is sent back.
```

This does not characterize or explain the meaning of `(UINT32 id)`.

A glaring omission is the lack of a table to describe the `NotificationClosed (UINT32 id)` parameter.  All the other parameters for methods and signals are qualified with such tables.

Empirical tests show notifications do not close using `Notify`'s return value:

```
 qdbus  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
       /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
        org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification         \
$(gdbus call --session                                          \
     -d org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
     -m org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                    \
                     "" 0 "" "sigma-ry" "corpus" [] {} 200      \
 | sed -e 's/(uint32\(.*\),)/\1/g'                            )
```

or

```
 qdbus  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
       /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
        org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification         \
$(gdbus call --session                                          \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                    \
                     "" 5 "" "sigma-ry" "corpus" [] {}  20      \
 | sed -e 's/(uint32\(.*\),)/\1/g'                            )
```

The notification does not close which would be the case if `(UINT32 id)` identified with the returned value of `Notify`.

Some more tests:

```
 gdbus call --session                                           \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification         \
$(gdbus call --session                                          \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                    \
                     "" 0 "" "sigma-ry" "corpus" [] {}     0    \
 | sed -e 's/(uint32\(.*\),)/\1/g'                            )
```

and even coercing a constant ID, by setting `UINT32 replaces_id` to 42 and `expire_timeout` to 0, it is seen that `CloseNotification` has no influence

```
 gdbus call --session                                           \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification         \
$(gdbus call --session                                          \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                    \
                     "" 42 "" "sigma-ry" "corpus" [] {}    0    \
 | sed -e 's/(uint32\(.*\),)/\1/g'                            )
```

The notification does not close even though the **`42`** makes the round trip throughout the methods as confirmed by

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
```

in the output

```
method call sender=:1.332 -> dest=org.freedesktop.Notifications serial=3 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string ""
   uint32 42
   string ""
   string "sigma-ry"
   string "corpus"
   array [
   ]
   array [
   ]
   int32 0
method call sender=:1.333 -> dest=org.freedesktop.Notifications serial=3 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=CloseNotification
   uint32 42
```

Also note the notification failure of a -1 timeout (documentation is [contradictory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185110/what-is-the-name-of-the-program-that-displays-the-notifications/189173#189173)):

```
  gdbus call --session                                          \
    -d  org.freedesktop.Notifications                           \
    -o /org/freedesktop/Notifications                           \
    -m  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify                    \
                     "" 42 "" "sigma-ry" "corpus" [] {}   -1
```

though this "works"

```
notify-send "test" -t -1
```

ref:
[What is the name of the program that displays the notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185110/what-is-the-name-of-the-program-that-displays-the-notifications/189173#189173) (document contradictions)
[How to force a new Notification in notify-osd to show up without waiting for the earlier one to exit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161662/how-to-force-a-new-notification-in-notify-osd-to-show-up-without-waiting-for-the/190399#190399)
[How do I use 'notify-send' to immediately replace an existing notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161851/how-do-i-use-notify-send-to-immediately-replace-an-existing-notification/190397#190397)

Bookmark:
[Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in/191518#191518)

Answer (score 0):

The `CloseNotification` method is defined as a D-Bus method by the [specification](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x408.html#command-close-notification). However, it only states that the ID is to be unique, non-zero, and less than MAXINT. It does not require that the ID be the PID of the calling process. You would need a way to get that ID before you could call the method successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm bit late, but I faced this problem myself today, and this may be useful to others!

First of all, install a patched `libnotify-bin` that supports the option `-p` to print the notification id:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:izx/askubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

Now an example script that sends a notification without timeout, and then closes the notification after a certain command is finished (in this case, just sleep 5 seconds):

```
notify-send 'Message...' -i dialog-information \
    -t 0 -h int:transient:1 \
    -p >/tmp/notification_id

sleep 5

qdbus org.freedesktop.Notifications \
     /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
      org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification \
    $(cat /tmp/notification_id)
```